# How to start a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request and judge request type in PHP?

Tags: php, request

I never see how is `PUT/DELETE` request sent.

How to do it in PHP?

I know how to send a GET/POST request with curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,   FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
```

But how to do `PUT`/`DELETE` request?

Comment: To get an PUT request, you cant do $_PUT['var'], but: `parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put_vars);`

Comment: `$_PUT` will fail,but `php://input` works.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For `DELETE` use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');`
For `PUT` use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);`

An alternative that doesn't rely on cURL being installed would be to use `file_get_contents` with a [custom HTTP stream context](http://php.net/manual/de/context.http.php).

```
$result = file_get_contents(
    'http://example.com/submit.php', 
    false, 
    stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'DELETE' 
        )
    ))
);
```

Check out these two articles on doing REST with PHP

- [http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306123233/https://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)
- [http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/making-restful-requests-in-php/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306123233/http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/making-restful-requests-in-php/)

Comment: It's working and I voted for that, but the drawback is that 'remote url opening  ' via file_get_contents may be blocked in configuration and that has be taken into account

Comment: @Ekonoval sure, just like it has to be taken into account that cURL might not be installed :)

Comment: FYI, links are no longer valid, ?s=restful returns no relevant results.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, if you want to send some "non-GET" request, you'll often work with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

And you'll use the [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) function to configure the request you're sending ; amongst the large amount of possible options, to change the request method, you'll be interested by at least those options *(quoting)* :

- `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` : A custom request method to use instead of "`GET`" or "`HEAD`" when doing a HTTP request. This is useful for doing "`DELETE`" or other, more obscure HTTP requests.
- `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` : `TRUE` to reset the HTTP request method to `GET`.
- `CURLOPT_POST` : `TRUE` to do a regular HTTP `POST`.
- `CURLOPT_PUT` : `TRUE` to HTTP `PUT` a file. The file to `PUT` must be set with `CURLOPT_INFILE` and `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE`.

Of course, `curl_setopt` is not the only function you'll use ; see the documentation page of [`curl_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) for an example of how to send a request with curl.

*(Yes, that example is pretty simple, and sends a `GET` request -- but you should be able to build from there ;-) )*

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST` is used to send GET/DELETE request,what about PUT/DELETE?

Comment: for PUT, you have `CURLOPT_PUT`, and for DELETE, it seems you'll have to use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`

Comment: Correct. That is what it says in the second article I've linked as well.