# PHP CURL PUT request with data

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

I need to do a PUT request sending json data, I wrote the code below but the data are not sent. Can someone help?

```
$url = 'https://example.com';
$data='{"example":"valor"}';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($curl);     
print_r($result);
```

thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting.

Comment: I have the same problem. Request is sent, but target server didn't get it's body. Did you find any suggestion?

Comment: @EvgeniyTimchenko I do not remember what exactly solved my problem but I've set some more options like (CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER)

Answer (score 1):

I think I know your issue. Try adding

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

The PHP docs allude that if you don't do this, executing the curl will just output the contents directly to a page, which if you're using this as a script that doesn't output anything, will obviously not show anything. This should make `$result` equal something, and then allow you to `print_r` it

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: @LucianoMarqueto I see that you have `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`, however for sake of troubleshooting, try replacing your `1`'s with `true`'s. Do you have any errors that you're getting form the page?

Comment: @LucianoMarqueto Does anything display on the page? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html). It is a wrapper around CURL that abstracts away all the configuration and gives you many convenience methods for easy use.

You can install Guzzle by following instructions in the following link:
http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#installation

Below is an example of how you could use guzzle to get what you want.

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';    
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $url = 'https://example.com';
    $data= array("example" => "valor");

    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('PUT', $url, [
        'json' => $data
    ]);

    print_r($response);
```

I have used Guzzle in place of raw CURL on many projects and found it to be a great time saver.

Answer (score 0):

For `PUT` use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);`

Refer this: [How to start a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request and judge request type in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153650/how-to-start-a-get-post-put-delete-request-and-judge-request-type-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've solved by changing

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
```

Before, this, curl try to post a file or something similar, with 100-continue, but we need to post json.